# Подскажите почему не работает?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Mне нужно, чтобы можно было добавлять несколько файлов на страницу, и код, в общем, работает. Но тот блок, который динамически создаётся, он уже не работает.

```
$('.block-file input[type="file"]').change(function(){
  $(this).prev().addClass("del");
  $(this).prev().removeClass("add");
  $(this).prev().find("span").text($(this).val());
  $(this).prev().attr('onclick', '$(this).parent().remove();')
  $(this).parent().parent().append('<div class="block-file"><a class="add" onclick="$(this).next().click();"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><span>Вы можете добавить фото</span></a><input type="file" style="visibility:hidden;width: 0;"></div>');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="block-file">
  <a class="add" onclick="$(this).next().click();"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><span>Вы можете добавить фото</span></a>
  <input type="file" style="visibility:hidden;width: 0;">
</div>
```

Comment: Паша, скажите, я правильно отредактировал ваш текст (ваши намеренья верно передал)?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что DOM модель уже вгружена в браузер, вы не можете изменять динамически вновь созданные объекты (они попросту не загружены). 
Для решения проблемы вам надо использовать

```
$('body').on('change', '.block-file input[type="file"]', function(){
   //... весь код тут
 });
```

Подробнее http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Паша "Спасибо большое" здесь выражается принятым ответом:).

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
$('.block-file input[type="file"]').change(function(){
```

используйте

```
$(document).on("change", '.block-file input[type="file"]', function(){
```